Flagging conversational comments
In my opinion, comments under this answer can be qualified as conversational and not relevant to the post.

Why? char limit
– Pimgd 2014-10-17 14:45:24Z, License: CC BY-SA 3.0


@Pimgd What? What char limit? See my update.
– maaartinus 2014-10-17 15:05:08Z, License: CC BY-SA 3.0


Comment character limit.
– Pimgd 2014-10-17 15:37:25Z, License: CC BY-SA 3.0


@Pimgd I see. No, I really wanted to write an answer rather than a comment as this is possibly more important than the other stuff. The most beautiful program is of no use if it hands out your password to everyone. I planed to add some more remarks, but there's so much already....
– maaartinus 2014-10-17 16:15:38Z, License: CC BY-SA 3.0

The crux, of the dialog: "You posted it as an answer because of the character limit for comments? No, I really wanted to write an answer."
I applied a no longer needed flag to each comment, since it's described as

This comment is outdated, conversational, or not relevant to this
post.

All flags were declined with no explanation.
Hence, the question: what sort of value these comments bear for a reader of this answer? If there's none and the comments should be removed, what should I have done instead of marking them as no longer needed?

"All flags were declined with no explanation." Comment flags can't be declined with a message. Only post flags can be declined with a message.

@Peilonrayz Understood, it's not a complaint, I'd like to know what's the appropriate action to take in this case.

Before I became a moderator I would flag a single comment as no longer needed and moderators would remove the entire discussion. Flagging more than one comment isn't necessary for users. And as the system supports declining all of the flags by declining one flag, you can more easily have the negative effects of declined flags affect your account.
I personally don't believe the exchange was:

Obsoleted by age. Where comments on older posts can become outdated. For instance, if technology changes a decade after a comment is posted. Or,

Conversational. As one user was telling the answerer that the answer was not an answer and should be a comment. The answerer indicated it was an answer. This was relevant to the post.


When flagging for a moderator you sometimes are rolling the dice. Different moderators can see different situations in different lights. I do not think the comments should be deleted.
